# How do I get a list of all the Google Chrome about: options?

Tags: google-chrome

What are all the available options are for typing about:xxxxx in the Omnibar (URL input box)?
Specifically, the change the options on the browser.

Answer (score 4):

```
about:about
```

gives a list of available parameters.

To the second question:

```
about:flags
```

Comment: Sweet, didn't know the first one. Nice histograms.

Comment: `about:version` shows the command-line arguments.